# imap_status() returning 0 in php

Tags: php, linux, outlook, office365, imap

till php 5.2 version imap_status() returns correct results.

But in php version 5.6.4 it returns,

```
stdClass Object
(
    [flags] => 0
)
```

I want to get Uivalidity through imap_status.

```
$mbox = imap_open ('{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}', "abc@abc.com", "password", OP_HALFOPEN)
      or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

$mbox_info = imap_status($mbox, "{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", SA_ALL);

print_r($mbox_info);
```

Comment: What options are you passing to imap_status?

Comment: imap_status($mbox, "{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", SA_ALL);

Comment: any suggestion?